# Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 error on a transaction call

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have implemented my own  project based on the "Commercial Paper" tutorial of Hyperledger docs, and it works on the basic-network but I want to run it on to the first-network, in order to add more channels and organizations. I have made the necesary changes to run it on  the first-network. I can install it and instantiate it, but when I call the transaction I'm getting an error. The Fabric version installed is 1.4.

I get following error:

```
2019-02-04T11:08:37.318Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: 
Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was 
Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last 
error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
at Network._initializeInternalChannel 
(/home/fabric/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric- 
samples/bimtrust/organization/contractor/application/node_modules/fabric- 
network/lib/network.js:120:12) at <anonymous>
Disconnect from Fabric gateway.
```

Does anyone knows why is unable to initialize channel?
I thought channel has been initialized before

### Here is my networkConnection.yalm:

```
name: "basic-network"

x-type: "hlfv1"

description: "The basic network"

version: "1.0"

channels:
# name of the channel
bimtrustchannel1:

orderers:
  - orderer.BIMTrust.com
# Required. list of peers from participating orgs
peers:
  peer0.org1.BIMTrust.com:
     endorsingPeer: true
     eventSource: true

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
  - peer0.org1.BIMTrust.com

certificateAuthorities:
  - ca-org1

orderers:
  orderer.BIMTrust.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:7050

grpcOptions:
  ssl-target-name-override: orderer.BIMTrust.com

peers:
peer0.org1.BIMTrust.com:
# this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
url: grpc://localhost:7051
grpcOptions:
  ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.BIMTrust.com
  request-timeout: 120001

certificateAuthorities:
  ca-org1:
    url: http://localhost:7054

httpOptions:
  verify: false

registrar:
  - enrollId: admin
    enrollSecret: adminpw

caName: ca-org1
```

Comment: I have seen a similar error where the connection.json (or network.yaml) being used by the client application does not match up to the actual fabric being used.  I would check this file for accuracy/completeness.

Comment: Yes, thank you I think it's ok. I Just edit the question and I have added the network connection.yaml

Comment: I wonder if the indentation of spaces/formatting of you peers: section is correct - maybe it is just the formatting in Stack Overflow - but worth checking.

Comment: Yes, that's identation of the code editor of Stack Overflow

Comment: When testing with the earlier 1.4-rc1 (release candidate test code) - I had to remove the "-" in front of enrollId: But it was giving a different error - might be worth removing

Comment: removed and same error. Thx

Comment: Did you get the solution for this so far? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Did you resolve this ? i'm also facing the same issue and i'm stuck here for past 3 days.